# No obtengo el valor de una sentencia con una variable de columna declara dentro de un trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy creando un trigger para auditoria
donde en la tabla `audProducto` guardo el nombre de la columna
el valor anterior y nuevo valor.

Cuando declaro el `@column` obtengo el nombre de la columna,
pero cuando lo utilizo para realizar una consulta
`declare @nombreI varchar(max) = (select  @column from inserted)`
el valor de `@nombreI` no trae el de la consulta sino el valor de la columna.

Ejemplo: `@column='NombreProducto'` en la consulta  deberia ser `@nombreI='Azucar'`
pero me trae  `@nombreI='NombreProducto'`

Si alguien sabe por que ocurre se lo agradeceria.

```
create trigger prueba
  on producto
  after update
  as
  --creamos una tabla para las columnas
 declare @tablaCo table(id int,nombre varchar(max))
--insertamos dentro de la tabla el id y los nombre de  las columnas
insert into @tablaCo(id,nombre) SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME ) as id,COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =  'producto'
--obtenemos la cantidad de registros
declare @count int = (select count(*) from @tablaCo)
while @count >0 
begin
    declare @id varchar(max)=(select top(1) id from @tablaCo  order by id)
    
    declare @column varchar(max)=(select  nombre from @tablaCo where id=@count )
  
   declare @nombreI varchar(max) = (select  @column from inserted )
    select @nombreI
    declare @nombreD varchar(max) = (select  @column from deleted  )
    select @nombreD
    if(@nombreD!=@nombreI)
    begin
    insert into audProducto values(@column,@nombreD,@nombreI)
    select * from audProducto
    end     

    select * from @tablaCo
    --borramos el valor dentro del blucle
    delete @tablaCo where id=@count
    --reasignamos el valor de count
    set @count = (select count(*) from @tablaCo)
end
```

ejemplo del resultado. que deseo obtener

```
tabla audProducto

|__CampoActualizado_|___NuevoValor__|_ValorAnterior_|
|   NombreProducto  | Azucar Blanca |  Azucar Blan. |
|   Precio          |   15.59       |    16.10      |
```

la tabla tiene N campos y solo deseo guardar lo que se esta actualizando.

Comment: Hola Gracias por responder en parte lo planeaba realizar como el ejemplo que mostraste, pero yo voy por ese camino por esta parte que me pidieron.**
EL log de auditoría deberá mostrar el histórico de actualizaciones por cada 
campo **
 voy a editar mi pregunta, con ejemplo de resultado que quisiera obtener con mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

No es que lo que pides no se pueda hacer, pero creo que estás escogiendo un camino **no adecuado**. Es mucho más fácil, que todo eso.

```
Create Table dbo.producto
             (
             id   Int
             Primary Key
           , col1 VarChar(10)
           , col2 VarChar(20)
           , col3 TinyInt
             );
Go

Create Table dbo.audproducto
             (
             myId int primary key identity(1,1)
           , id       Int
           , new_col1 VarChar(10)
           , old_col1 VarChar(10)
           , new_col2 VarChar(20)
           , old_col2 VarChar(20)
           , new_col3 TinyInt
           , old_col3 TinyInt
           , dateEvent datetime2 default(getdate())
             );
Go
Insert into dbo.producto (id,col1, col2, col3)
values
(1,null ,'b'    ,0),
(2,null ,'b'    ,0),
(3,null ,'b'    ,1),
(4,'a'  ,'b'    ,0),
(5,'a'  ,null   ,2),
(6,'a'  ,null   ,3),
(7,'a'  ,null   ,0),
(8,'a'  ,null   ,4),
(9,'a'  ,'b'    ,3);
GO
```

La primera diferencia, es que mi tabla de `audProducto` es igual que la tabla de `producto`, pero contiene columnas para los valores "*nuevo*" y "*viejo*". Además le he añadido dos columnas, para tener una clave primaria y la fecha.

El trigger es supersimple, porque solo tengo que relacionar las pseudotablas inserted y deleted para tener el valor de lo anterior y lo que se está modificando.

Con ellos, inserto en la tabla de auditorias.

```
Create Trigger prueba On dbo.producto
After Update
As
BEGIN
    ;WITH data AS (
        Select i.id as id
             , i.col1 as newCol1
             , d.col1 as oldCol1
             , i.col2 as newCol2
             , d.col2 as oldCol2
             , i.col3 as newCol3
             , d.col3 as oldCol3
            from inserted i inner join deleted d on i.id = d.id
        )
        Insert into dbo.audproducto (id, new_col1, old_col1, new_col2, old_col2, new_col3, old_col3)
        Select * from data;

END
GO
```

La segunda diferencia más importante, es que una update, no tiene porque ser una fila, y lo que estás planteando, es un bucle para una sola fila, cuando la update puede tener `n` filas. Por tanto tendrías que envolver todo el bucle en otro bucle, para hacerlo para el número de filas que entraran.

Además de tener que utilizar una query dinámica, para obtener el valor, y encima tendrías que andar realizando cast a tipos de datos, que te pueden presentar problemas para las asignaciones de los valores.

```
Update dbo.producto Set col1 = 'CambioA'
    where col1 is null;
```

Múltiples filas, resueltas.

[image: Resultado]

Un segundo ejemplo que toca las mismas filas y otras.

```
Update dbo.producto Set col2 = 'Nuevo'
    , col3 = 5
    Where id in (1,3,5,7,9);
```

[image: Resultado2]

Luego si cuando quieras recuperar los valores de la tabla de auditoría los quieres como lo intentas anotar, solo tienes que hacer un unpivot. Y ya representas cada columna como si fuera una fila.

Si tienes un Sql Server 2016 o superior, además tienes la posibilidad de utilizar el versionado de tabla.

[Versionado de tabla](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/19/versionado-de-tabla-sql-2016/)

[Auditoria de tabla con triggers](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/07/auditoria-de-tabla-con-triggers/)